# request.getRemoteUser==null; how to log all traffic from apache to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache2, mod-jk

I have a connector defined as:

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" enableLookups="false" tomcatAuthentication="false"        scheme="https" 
    secure="true" 
    address="127.0.0.1" 
    port="8009" />
```

however, request.getRemoteUser is returning null.

my question is how can i make Apache log 'everything' it sends to Tomcat?  i have apache and mod_jk log levels set to 'debug'.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the `mod_jk` logs should do the trick:

```
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel    debug
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying, however, I do have mod_jk logs set to debug. Still do not see the headers.